# Persisting custom objects temporarily using swift 3

Tags: core-data, swift3

What is the best way to persist *custom objects temporarily* in my iOS app? By "temporarily," I mean the object "goes away" when the app is closed.

- **UserDefaults** doesn't persist custom objects (from what I've seen).
- **Keychain** is overkill because I don't need to encrypt any of the data.
- **CoreData** (in-memory) seems to be the only other option but it seems a bit heavy.

Are there any other options?

The apple documentation for [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1) seems like a good place to start if that's the way to go, but after looking at the examples, I couldn't even get them to compile.

*** UPDATED SOLUTION ***
I decided to go with a singleton after all...

```
    // Where userDto inherits NSObject, NSCoding and provides "func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)" and "init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)" methods per the NSCoding protocol.

    // Store
    PersistenceManager.instance.store(userDto)
    PersistenceManager.instance.storeTemporary(userDto)

    // Retrieve
    if let dto:UserDto = PersistenceManager.instance.retrieve() {
       // Do something..
    }

    if let dto:UserDto = PersistenceManager.instance.retrieveTemporary() {
       // Do something..
    }

    import Foundation
    import CoreData

    final class PersistenceManager {
       static let instance = PersistenceManager()

       private var localStore = Dictionary<String, NSCoding?>()

       private init() {
       }

       // MARK: -- Store

       public func store<T>(_ data:T) where T: NSCoding {
          let key = getKey(for: T.self)
          let archivedNSCoding:NSData = archive(data)
          let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
          userDefaults.set(archivedNSCoding, forKey: key)
          userDefaults.synchronize()
       }

       public func storeTemporary<T>(_ data:T) where T: NSCoding {
          let key = getKey(for: T.self)
          localStore[key] = data
       }


       // MARK: -- Retrieve

       public func retrieve<T>() -> T? where T: NSCoding {
          let key = getKey(for: T.self)
          if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? NSData {
             if let unarchived = unarchive(with: data) as? T {
                return unarchived
             }
          }

          return nil
       }

       public func retrieveTemporary<T>() -> T? where T: NSCoding {
          let key = getKey(for: T.self)
          return localStore[key] as? T
       }

       // MARK: -- Remove

       public func remove<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> T? where T: NSCoding {
          if let data:T = retrieve() {
             let key = getKey(for: type)
             let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
             userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
             userDefaults.synchronize()
             return data
          } else {
             return nil
          }
       }

       public func removeTemporary<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> T? where T: NSCoding {
          let key = getKey(for: type)
          let data:T? = localStore[key] as? T
          localStore.removeValue(forKey: key)
          return data
       }

       // MARK: -- Miscellaneous

       public func exists<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> Bool where T: NSCoding {
          let key = getKey(for: type)
          return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) != nil
       }

       private func storeTemporary(data:NSCoding, forKey key: String) {
          localStore[key] = data
       }

       // MARK: -- Helper methods

       private func getKey<T>(for type: T.Type) -> String where T: NSCoding {
          return String(describing: T.self)
       }

       private func archive(_ data: NSCoding) -> NSData {
          return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: data) as NSData
       }

       private func unarchive(with data: NSData) -> NSCoding? {
          if let unarchivedNSCoding = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as Data) as? NSCoding {
             return unarchivedNSCoding
          } else {
             return nil
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: The typical way to store objects until the app is terminated is to just hold them in a variable. UserDefaults and Keychain both persist data between launches, so I'm not certain why they're on your list. In-memory Core Data is fine if you want the features of Core Data. But what problem is "a variable that holds the data" not solving for you? (Note that UserDefaults can absolutely persist custom objects; you just have to encode them. The same is true of Keychain. But "persist" seems to be the opposite of what you want.)

Comment: @RobNapier - I don't want to use a variable because the data needs to be shared back and forth between view controllers within the same storyboard and between view controllers that reside in different storyboards. Using a global variable, singleton class, etc. would be messy; delegates, unwinding, etc. also won't work for all my navigation scenarios. Keychain and UserDefaults are on my list because I wasn't sure if there was an option that I didn't know about to persist temporarily; regardless, I wouldn't want them for the stated reasons.

Comment: If you use Core Data, you're still going to have a variable that you have to hand around or put in a singleton (the managed object context). User defaults is exactly a singleton (`UserDefaults.standard`), and keychain is effectively a singleton. The way you generally solve the problem you're describing is either with singletons or by passing around data (generally called "injection"). Singletons are much (much!) simpler, but can sometimes be harder to test. I generally have a singleton that holds all the "global variables" but is only used by the view controllers.

Comment: But if you're new to iOS development, I highly recommend you just use a shared singleton here. It's how we've done it since the earliest days of Cocoa. When you run into problems with singletons (usually around unit test), then you'll have some experience to judge other approaches that people suggest. (Note that the singleton you create should *not* be your app delegate. That's a really common mistake. Just create a new shared singleton to hold the data.)

Comment: @RobNapier - went with the singleton, see my answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some convincing, I did decide to go with a singleton.

In my particular case scenario, I will only need to store 1 version of any one of several particular object types in temporary storage (hence class name as the key). I also decided I might need the option to store these same objects in UserDefaults, so I added that code as well.

**Usage**

```
// Where userDto inherits NSObject, NSCoding and provides "func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)" and "init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)" methods per the NSCoding protocol.

// Store
PersistenceManager.instance.store(userDto)
PersistenceManager.instance.storeTemporary(userDto)

// Retrieve
if let dto:UserDto = PersistenceManager.instance.retrieve() {
   // Do something..
}

if let dto:UserDto = PersistenceManager.instance.retrieveTemporary() {
   // Do something..
}

import Foundation
import CoreData

final class PersistenceManager {
   static let instance = PersistenceManager()

   private var localStore = Dictionary<String, NSCoding?>()

   private init() {
   }

   // MARK: -- Store

   public func store<T>(_ data:T) where T: NSCoding {
      let key = getKey(for: T.self)
      let archivedNSCoding:NSData = archive(data)
      let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
      userDefaults.set(archivedNSCoding, forKey: key)
      userDefaults.synchronize()
   }

   public func storeTemporary<T>(_ data:T) where T: NSCoding {
      let key = getKey(for: T.self)
      localStore[key] = data
   }


   // MARK: -- Retrieve

   public func retrieve<T>() -> T? where T: NSCoding {
      let key = getKey(for: T.self)
      if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? NSData {
         if let unarchived = unarchive(with: data) as? T {
            return unarchived
         }
      }

      return nil
   }

   public func retrieveTemporary<T>() -> T? where T: NSCoding {
      let key = getKey(for: T.self)
      return localStore[key] as? T
   }

   // MARK: -- Remove

   public func remove<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> T? where T: NSCoding {
      if let data:T = retrieve() {
         let key = getKey(for: type)
         let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
         userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
         userDefaults.synchronize()
         return data
      } else {
         return nil
      }
   }

   public func removeTemporary<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> T? where T: NSCoding {
      let key = getKey(for: type)
      let data:T? = localStore[key] as? T
      localStore.removeValue(forKey: key)
      return data
   }

   // MARK: -- Miscellaneous

   public func exists<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> Bool where T: NSCoding {
      let key = getKey(for: type)
      return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) != nil
   }

   private func storeTemporary(data:NSCoding, forKey key: String) {
      localStore[key] = data
   }

   // MARK: -- Helper methods

   private func getKey<T>(for type: T.Type) -> String where T: NSCoding {
      return String(describing: T.self)
   }

   private func archive(_ data: NSCoding) -> NSData {
      return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: data) as NSData
   }

   private func unarchive(with data: NSData) -> NSCoding? {
      if let unarchivedNSCoding = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as Data) as? NSCoding {
         return unarchivedNSCoding
      } else {
         return nil
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If your dataset is pretty small and won't increase much, you can always try writing to JSON files using `JSONSerialization` or the new `Codable` protocols once you upgrade to Swift4.

If you have a data set that increases over time, want to do some more advanced logic on either CoreData, SQLite or Realm will do. I suggest taking a look at [Realm](http://realm.io), it is a very friendly database and they claim it performs better than SQLite and therefore CoreData do. CoreData uses SQLite under the hood.

With realm you can easily write an object and with a simple call to realm write and you're done.
If you have no experience in SQL whatsoever, either Realm or CoreData are the ways to go.

I myself dislike CoreData as I do prefer having access to SQL and I don't like having to wrap my head around an entirely new system that has it's own quirks and ideas to deal with. It does ofcourse integrate extremely well into iOS and Xcode, which might be a big plus for you as well.

Realm's own database browser is well, sufficient but lacks plenty of features and doesn't support decrypting encrypted Realm databases ( which is really weird to me ). Realm is also quite heavy on the code size of things, but you can get rid of quite a bit by running the stripping scripts during build.

Comment: Does Realm have the equivalent of a temporary in-memory data store that disappears when the app exits?

Comment: @TomHarrington You can run Realm completely in memory ( like SQLite can too ). Realm also has an easy write-out function if you want to actually save yoru current data store ( with optional encryption again ).

Comment: @AntwanvanHoudt - Thank you Antwan, but any db would be overkill for what I need, all I need to do is temporarily persist the data of a single entity between view controllers that span different storyboards. I don't like the idea of "variables" in the view controller, singletons, delegates, unwinding, etc. as none of these will work with all navigation scenarios.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean "all navigation scenarios." I've written many Cocoa apps for over ten years on both Mac and iOS, and singletons have handled every navigation situation I've seen. The problems with singletons generally have nothing to do with navigation problems. Can you describe specific navigation issue you're encountering in your current app that this is a problem for?

Comment: @RobNapier - the "navigational issues" I describe don't pertain to the singleton, the others do when going back and forth between view controllers and between view controllers in different storyboards, or situations where no navigation controller is being used. I read that singletons are buggy for some reason and wanted to avoid them.

Comment: @RobNapier - singletons are hard to test, not buggy.

Comment: If you haven't done much iOS development, start with singletons. If your only reason for avoiding them is that you read they were hard to test, then wait until you have some experience with them. It's not untrue; but it isn't nearly as huge an issue as I believe you're thinking, and none of the things you're discussing fixes it (you're just creating other singletons that you have less control over). Storyboards and arbitrary VCs are trivial w/ singletons. Most of the popular non-singleton approaches don't use Storyboards (and so give up all the benefits of Storyboards).

Comment: Note that moving between storyboards has absolutely no impact on how you pass data around. Things that are easy w/ Storyboards are generally easy with multiple Storyboards, and things that are hard w/ Storyboards are hard no matter how many or few you have. The same is true for navigation controllers. It's using Storyboards that make certain patterns hard (specifically Storyboards make non-singleton patterns harder).

Comment: I personally use singletons because the specific requirement of my app is one account, I don't need several. That said, you can achieve near-OOP compliance in C, the difference being you have to pass a lot more parameters. I personally feel segue's in iOS break this a bit and make it harder to sometimes do what you want, but probably more experienced and better developers have good paragidms to deal with that problem specifically. So I hope someone can correct me on that and teach me something too!

Comment: @AntwanvanHoudt - whet with the singleton, see my answer. Thanks for the help.